I need my query to run faster, and I don't understand why it's doing a table scan
I'm struggling with how to improve my queries.   Here's the scenario.
I have to report on bus promptness.   I have bus positions, in the table bus_dynamic_history.   I have bus journeys, in table bus_journeys.   I have bus stops, in bus_timetables.
Table 'bus_dynamic_history' has a lot of records of bus positions, recorded as sdo_geometry points, but no indication of whether they're near a bus stop or not.   The table 'bus_journeys' joins with 'bus_dynamic_history' on 'operatorcode' and 'linename'.   Table 'bus_timetables' joins with 'bus_journeys' on 'unique_journey' and 'runningboard', and has an sdo_geometry point as a location.
I want to know whether a bus was early or late at a certain stop.   So I'm trying to compare each bus position with that of a known bus stop, by querying whether it's within 5 meters of that stop or not.
Here is the query I'm trying to run:
SELECT b.uniquejourney journey, a.journeyid, a.vehicleid, a.operatorcode, a.linename, c.atcocode, trunc(a.capturetime) cdate, 
b.runningboard board, b.starttime, b.endtime, c.atcocode stop,  sdo_geom.sdo_distance(a.location, c.location) meters, min(to_char(a.capturetime, 'HH24MI')) ctime
FROM bus_dynamic_history a, bus_journeys b, bus_timetables c 
WHERE a.operatorcode = b.operator AND a.linename = b.linename AND b.uniquejourney = c.uniquejourney AND b.runningboard = c.runningboard
AND a.journeyid = b.starttime --AND a.operatorcode = 'ADER' AND linename = '38' --AND b.unique_journey = '11cs8'
AND c.stopflag = 'T'
and sdo_within_distance( c.location, a.location, 'distance = 5' ) = 'TRUE'
AND a.lastupdated BETWEEN '19/05/2024 00:00' AND '22/05/2024 23:59'
GROUP BY b.uniquejourney, a.journeyid, a.vehicleid, a.operatorcode, a.linename, trunc(a.capturetime), b.runningboard, b.starttime, b.endtime, c.atcocode, sdo_geom.sdo_distance(a.location, c.location)

I have indexes on:
bus_dynamic_history(lastupdated)
bus_dynamic_history(operatorcode)
bus_dynamic_history(location)
bus_journeys(uniquejourney)
bus_journeys(starttime)
bus_timetables(uniquejourney)
bus_timetables(location)

Here is the oracle explain plan
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 801895608
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                              | Name                |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |                     |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                         |                     |
|   2 |   FILTER                               |                     |
|   3 |    HASH JOIN                           |                     |
|   4 |     HASH JOIN                          |                     |
|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | BUS_JOURNEYS        |
|   6 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | BUS_TIMETABLES      |
|   7 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| BUS_DYNAMIC_HISTORY |
|   8 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | BDH_LASTUPD         |
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Table 'bus_dynamic_history' has 40 million rows, 'bus_journey' has about 4500 and 'bus_timetables' has about 28000.
This query runs in about 15 minutes, but I need it to be a lot quicker.
I don't understand why it's doing a full table access on bus_journeys and bus_timetables.
I was hoping it would do an index scan ... can anyone advise me on what I need to do to  make it run in a not-crap length of time?
I have tried various indexes and permutations, but it's not running fast enough.   It takes about 15 minutes as it is, but I want it to be faster, and I can't understand why it's doing full table scans
After Jon Heller's suggestion, I ran the query with a /*+ monitor */ hint, and then ran the suggested query on report_sql_monitor.  All I got was this:
    SQL> select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor('923rrmjxwccq4') from dual;

DBMS_SQLTUNE.REPORT_SQL_MONITOR('923RRMJXWCCQ4')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL Monitoring Report

1 row selected.
I've got the report to work now - can't figure out how to attach the output file, but this is a screenshot of the output:
sql_monitor_report

The full tables scans are likely not the main problem in this query. Reading and joining a few thousand rows probably takes less than a second - unless there's a sort of unexpected Cartesian product or the rows contains gigabytes of data. I'd guess the issue is that Oracle is applying the expensive sdo_within_distance function too soon. To know for sure, run the query again and generate a SQL Monitor Report with select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor('enter SQL_ID here') from dual; That report will tell us actual and estimated times and cardinalities so we can troubleshoot better.

Do you store the time values as string? You should never do that, it's a design flaw. Store always proper DATE values. Apart from that you should learn modern (well it exists now for 25 years) ANSI join syntax.

Do you have an index on stopflag and lastupdated?

To understand your SQL could you please send us the DDL for the forllowing objects  bus_dynamic_history , bus_journeys  and  bus_timetables

@jon - thanks for your suggestion - I did what you said, but the only output was 'SQL Monitoring Report'

@NigelDams Make sure that you have ran the query somewhat recently, as the monitoring cache will run out after a while. And double-check that you have the right SQL_ID. If that still doesn't work, you can generate similar results using the gather_plan_statistics hint approach.

@JonHeller thanks - I've got it working now - can't seem to attach the resulting htm file, but I've put a screenshot of the output in the main body of the question.

@WernfriedDomscheit - thanks for your comments - I am using char(4) to store the start time of a bus journey, but that's only because the 'journeyid' value provided in the bus telemetry is a char(4) ... it just happens to be the same as the start time.    I'm not sure how making it a date would help?     Also, I've tested queries with old-fashioned join syntax versus the more modern style and there's no discernible difference in run-time

How can you store a value like '19/05/2024 00:00' in a CHAR(4) column? Do you have all indexes on single column or compound index?

@WernfriedDomscheit - I'm not trying to store a whole date in four chars.    I have to get my bus timetable data from 'cif' files provided by the bus authority.  They contain a four-character 'start time' for a given journey.   That's what 'start time' is in the 'bus_journeys' table.    From the bus telemetry provided by the bus itself, I have 'capturetime' which is sent every few seconds and is a date variable, and 'journeyid' which is the start time of the journey - whether or not the bus actually leaves at that time - and that also is four characters.

@NigelDams The execution plan and the query imply the issue is with sdo_within_distance. Unfortunately, I don't think this is a typical Oracle performance problem. Per the manual, "The SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE operator is not suitable for performing spatial joins.", but I think that's what you are doing. I changed the tags and hopefully an Oracle Spatial expert will chime in.

Without table definition and sample data we can jut guess.
Assuming that sdo_within_distance is the bottleneck, you can try similar to this one:
WITH t AS (
    SELECT b.uniquejourney journey, a.journeyid, a.vehicleid, a.operatorcode, a.linename, c.atcocode, a.capturetime, 
        b.runningboard board, b.starttime, b.endtime, c.atcocode STOP,  
        c.location AS history_LOCATION, a.location AS timetable_LOCATION
    FROM bus_dynamic_history a
        JOIN bus_journeys b ON a.operatorcode = b.operator AND a.linename = b.linename AND a.journeyid = b.starttime
        JOIN bus_timetables c ON b.uniquejourney = c.uniquejourney AND b.runningboard = c.runningboard
    WHERE a.operatorcode = 'ADER' 
        AND linename = '38' 
        --AND b.unique_journey = '11cs8'
        AND c.stopflag = 'T'
        AND a.lastupdated BETWEEN DATE '2024-05-19' AND DATE '2024-05-23')
SELECT MIN(TO_CHAR(a.capturetime, 'HH24MI')) ctime, 
    journey, journeyid, vehicleid, operatorcode, linename, atcocode, ...
FROM t
WHERE sdo_within_distance( timetable_LOCATION, history_LOCATION, 'distance = 5' ) = 'TRUE'
GROUP BY journey, journeyid, vehicleid, operatorcode, linename, atcocode;

Looks like, you created indexes on single columns. You can also create composite index, for example:
CREATE INDEX dynamic_history_ind ON bus_dynamic_history (operatorcode, linename, journeyid);
CREATE INDEX journeys_ind1 ON bus_journeys(operator, linename, starttime);
CREATE INDEX journeys_ind2 ON bus_journeys(uniquejourney, runningboard);
CREATE INDEX timetables_ind bus_timetables(uniquejourney, runningboard);


Thanks - I've tried what you said, including all the indexes.     It doesn't change the run-time, it still takes about 15 minutes for that date range.  For what it's worth, if I halve the date range, the query takes about half as long, and if I make it just one day, it runs in about 4 minutes.

A common table expression probably won't help because Oracle can rewrite the entire query into a single step as part of an optimizer transformation. However, there are some tricks that can prevent those optimizations and force Oracle to run the statement in a specific order. For example, adding a seemingly worthless ROWNUM column to the inner query will force it to run first, and save the sdo_within_distance operator until the last step. Although that change will only help if the number of rows is significantly limited before the spatial operation runs.
